# angular.js:11598 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined in angularjs modal

Tags: angularjs

i try to call modal instance from main page controller but i get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
are anyone help me to solve the problem

my main page controller is

```
app.controller('unitMasterCntlr', ['$scope', 'toaster', '$state',
'$http', 'emodal', '$timeout', '$compile','$filter','$modal','$rootScope',
function ($scope, toaster, $state, $http, emodal, $timeout, $compile,
DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $interval,$filter,$modal,$rootScope) {
```

and module is

```
angular.module('app', ['datatables','ui.select2','easyModalService',
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'ngStorage',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.utils',
'ui.load',
'ui.jq',
'oc.lazyLoad',
'pascalprecht.translate',
'ui.mask']);
```

and modal calling code as

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'tpl/UnitMasterModal.jsp',
                controller: 'modalcntrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });
```

modal controller is

```
app.controller('modalcntrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
            $scope.items = items;

            $scope.selected = {
                item: $scope.items[0]
            };

            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }]);
```

where item is an array having some response value that i want to display on modal 
iam new to angularjs... plz  help me to solve this

Comment: for `ui.bootstrap` it's `$uibModal` not `$modal`

Comment: it met with another error       "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- unitMasterCntlr"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved when i change my module like this

```
app.controller('unitMasterCntlr', ['$scope', 'toaster', '$state','$http', 'emodal', '$timeout', '$compile','$filter','$modal','$rootScope',function ($scope, toaster, $state, $http, emodal,$filter,$modal,$rootScope) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this issue is probably caused by a mismatch of your Angular js and Angular Bootstrap UI js libraries.

Please note that the latest version of AngularJS Bootstrap UI 0.12.1 requires Angular 1.2.16+

Check your includes and that the versions are compatible.

Comment: my bootstrap ui version is 0.12.0 and angular is 1.3.0